# Android bluetooth scanner in c#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, bluetooth

i'm trying to develop an application in c# (in Xamarin workspace) which displays all nearby Bluetooth devices ( Classic and BLE devices ). 
All the devices must be loaded into a list view.
Can someone help me with how to start doing this application, or to direct me to identical projects that i can learn from them how to do it ?